# Unable to add comments to document using details pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, comments

I have a document library where I am experiencing inconsistency in being able to add comments via file details pane. Some files have a comment box available while others don't.  It doesn't appear to be based on file type, and as far as I know none of the files have any special editing restrictions such as read-only or password protection.

Is anyone aware of common reasons a file might not allow a comment to be added and/or is there a way to resolve this through sharepoint settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comments to document using Details pane is applicable to **NON-OFFICE Files**, such as PDF, images.

[image]

[image]

If you want add comments for **MS Office Files (Word, Excel, PowerPoint)**, please follow the steps:

- 1.Open the document in browser

[image]

- 2.**Insert** >> **New Comment**

[image]

[image]

Here is a good Blog about Documents comments in SharePoint Online.

- [6 ways to add comments to documents in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-to-add-comments-to-documents-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you, somehow I got the misunderstanding that this feature was available FOR office files; we have a wide variety of file types and I couldn't make the connection.  Thanks again for the help!